# How to have a custom rounding function?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Basically, I need `FormatNumber` to behave slightly differently. Of course, we can write our own `MyFormatNumber`, but basically, it should return the following:

`59.080` returns `59.08`
`59.081` returns `59.08`
`59.082` returns `59.08`
`59.083` returns `59.08`
`59.084` returns `59.09` ←
`59.085` returns `59.09`
`59.086` returns `59.09`
`59.087` returns `59.09`
`59.088` returns `59.09`
`59.089` returns `59.09`

As you can see, the only difference is when the 3rd decimal place is a 4, then I would like to round up. That is, when the input's third decimal place is 4 or greater, then do a round up, otherwise round down.

How can we do such a function in Classic ASP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom rounding function could be implemented like this:

```
Function CustomRound(n)
  If n * 1000 Mod 10 < 4 Then
    CustomRound = Int(n * 100) / 100
  Else
    CustomRound = (Int(n * 100) + 1) / 100
  End If
End Function
```